# Pass an object into a directive as an attribute Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm trying to pass data to a component, it seems I can pass only strings, is there a way to make angular recognize the data input as an array of objects

component html :

```
<app-mycomponent
      url="https://url.com/getall" 
      data ="[{ name: 'a', required: ture},
              { name: 'b', required: false}]"
      ></app-mycomponent>
```

component ts :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomponent',
    templateUrl: './component.component.html',
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() url: string;
  @Input() data : any;
}
```

Comment: Yep, change it from `data=` to `[data]=` (also you have a type there for `true`)

Comment: And please, don't use `any`. The whole point of TypeScript is to make code maintainable and safe by introducing types. Define types, and use them.

Comment: thanks, you saved me a lot of time, and I used 'any' for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [one-way data-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) `[data]`:

```
<app-mycomponent
      url="https://url.com/getall" 
      [data] ="[{ name: 'a', required: true},
              { name: 'b', required: false}]">
</app-mycomponent>
```